# AngularJS: using directives in other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is my first AngularJS directive, so please be kind :D

I'm trying to use the ladda directive inside a directive I'm writing, I used the 'require' attribute, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code:

*ladda-button.js*

```
app.directive('laddaButton', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: -100,
    require: 'ladda',
    scope: {
        ngIf: '@',
        laddaVariable: '=',
        buttonClass: '@',
        iconClass: '@',
        text: '@',
        loadingText: '@',
        onClick: '&'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: './tpl/directives/button.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        console.log($scope.laddaVariable)
        var auxText = $scope.text

        $scope.loading = function () {
            $scope.text = $scope.loadingText;
            var stop = $scope.$watch('laddaVariable', function (newVal, old) {
                if (!newVal) {
                    $scope.text = auxText;
                    stop();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
});
```

*button.html*

```
     <button class="{{buttonClass}}" ng-click="onClick(); loading();"  ladda=laddaVariable data-style="expand-right"><i class="{{iconClass}}"></i>{{text}}</button>
```

Here's an implementation:

```
         <ladda-button on-click="fake()"
              ng-if="true"
              ladda-variable="test"
              icon-class="fa fa-gear"
              button-class="btn btn-addon btn-primary"
              text="Richiedi credenziali SIP"
              loading-text="Caricando..."></ladda-button>
```

Here's the controller:

```
  $scope.test = false;
  $scope.fake = function(){
         $scope.test = true;

         $timeout(function(){
               $scope.test = false;
            }, 2000);
          }
  }
```

Comment: Change `on-click="fake()"` to `ng-click="fake()"`

Comment: What should this change? The function in "on-click" is correctly called, as you can see the change in the variable text. The only thing not working is the ladda icon